# Modeling player interactions in multi-dimensional rating systems

Tags: multivariate-analysis, ranking, rating, elo

In traditional rating systems (such as Elo), a player's strength is represented by a single scalar value, which is assumed to be consistent across different opponents. However, in some games, the interaction between players can introduce complexities that aren't captured by a single number. This leads to potential scenarios where $p_1>p_2$​, $p_2>p_3$, and $p_3>p_1$​, suggesting that player strengths might be better represented in an $n$-dimensional space (ex. $\text{style}_1$ beats $\text{style}_2$ and $\text{style}_2$ beats $\text{style}_3$ but $\text{style}_3$ beats $\text{style}_1$).

1. Are there established methods or models in the mathematical literature that deal with such multi-dimensional interactions in the context of rating or ranking systems?
2. How might one approach the problem of clustering players based on their multi-dimensional strengths or styles?

Any references or insights would be appreciated.

Comment: See for instance https://dclaz.github.io/mELO/  Googling for "multidimensional ELO" gives many relevant hits!  See also http://universalrating.com/  which is specific for chess, the different dimensions being different time controls